# htaccess redirecting css, js files too

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My htaccess redirecting css, js files too. I tried this but didn't work. My all js files redirecting to page.php.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ page.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: RewriteConds only apply to the immediately following RewriteRule. You have made your first rule dependent on the two conditions that the requested URL does not match an existing file of folder here, but the second one is completely independent of that.

Comment: To make life a bit easier, you could redirect all requests to non-existing files to index.php (so you only have one rewrite rule in your htaccess) and then use a router to handle the routing. That way, you have the URL logic in your application, which makes it much easier to migrate it over to a new web server (like nginx) in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows. So, you would need to repeat these conditions for the second rule as well.

However, depending on your URL structure, you may not need these conditions at all if you just make your regex more specific - this would also be more efficient since file system checks are relatively expensive.

For example, assuming your "language code" (optional first path segment) consists of 2 lowercase letters and the `page` URL path segment does not contain dots (that could otherwise be confused with file extensions) then you could rewrite your directives like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]*)$ page.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ page.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Since the regex are now more restrictive and no longer conflict, the order of these directives does not matter.

The `NC` flags are not required unless you have mixed case language codes.

You could also take this a step further and combine these two rules into one by making the language path segment optional. The `lang` URL parameter will now always be present, but could be empty.

```
RewriteRule ^(?:([a-z]{2})/)?([^/]*)$ page.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```