# how to rewrite the htaccess rules to redirect to css files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

##### The goal is to be able to access `CSS` files this way `/css/index.css` in the `index.php` file, but the real path to the CSS files are `./resources/styles/index.css`.

###### If user opens the website e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com/`

It must redirect the user to the `public/index.php` file (entry-point), but at the same time all CSS files (which are in real are located under `resources/styles/` directory, and they must be accessible using this url:`https://stackoverflow.com/css/index.css`, and applied accordinly to the HTML page.

My current project structure:

```
public/
├─ .htaccess
├─ index.php
resources/
├─ styles/
│  ├─ index.css
│  ├─ main.css
.htaccess
```

My `./public/index.php` file (**MUST be the entry-point**):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
    {{-- but the actual path to index.css is "./resources/styles/index.css"--}}
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried this `.htaccess` config (from the root directory), but it returns me `Not Found - 404` page:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /resources/styles/.*
RewriteRule ^resources/styles/(.*)$ /css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

What do I miss here? Please describe it with some extra details if possible.

My `./public/.htaccess` config:

```
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Also, what would be the best way to do the same for these(`[js, fonts, images]`) types?

I know that this could be done in apache config this way:

```
...
Alias /css "/var/www/html/resources/styles"
<Directory /var/www/html/resources/styles>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
</Directory>
...
```

Please, correct me if something is missing in the apache config.

But, currently, I need to be able to use the `.htaccess` file.

I have tried reading this posts:

- [htacess redirecting to js & css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63232272/htacess-redirecting-to-js-css-files);
- [htaccess RewriteRule redirecting to parent directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787008/htaccess-rewriterule-redirecting-to-parent-directory)
- [htaccess redirecting css, js files too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64097561/htaccess-redirecting-css-js-files-too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# rewrite css files to their actual path
RewriteRule ^css/(.+\.css)$ resources/styles/$1 [L,NC]

# rewrite js files to their actual path
RewriteRule ^js/(.+\.js)$ resources/js/$1 [L,NC]

# write root to public/
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]

RewriteRule ^(?!resources/).* public/$0 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Sorry, @anubhava, I did not mention correctly that the `entry-point` of the PHP **must be** `public/index.php` file. The Apache server by default(in my case) is pointing to the root directory (so the main `.htaccess` from the root) is used to redirect to the `public/index.php`. Could you post the changes required to do this in the comments or edit your answer, please? As If I replace the last 2 lines with`RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]` (as it was before), and try to open my `/css/index.css` file, it redirects me to the `public/index.php` instead of `css` file.

Comment: ok check my updated answer to be used in site root .htaccess

Comment: Yeah, but if I have `RewriteRule ^resources/ public/index.php [L,NC]` this still, does not work (and the `resources/styles/index.css` redirects me to the main page `public/index.php`. and if set it like this: `RewriteRule ^public/index.php [L,NC]`, it works, but favicon error appears

Comment: Where is your `favicon.ico` located?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I wanted to have for my project! You really helped me out! Much obliged!
But, using this config I have the error file `favicon.ico` and the error message is `"object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server..."`. Could you please:
1 let me know how I could fix this for favicon or any other files that could throw the same error?
2 provide me with a vital configuration .htaccess file (that will handle most of the files), please? 
3 let me know if there are any good sources/books to learn .htaccess (as official docs is a bit hard to read for me), please?

Comment: Sorry I had a typo. Last line should be `RewriteRule !^resources/ public/index.php [L,NC]` (please check updated answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238715/discussion-between-utmost-creator-and-anubhava).